# MapStruct does not detect setters in builder

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jackson, mapstruct, immutables-library

I am building a simple REST service using spring. I separated my entities from DTOs and I made the DTOs immutable using [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/). I needed mapping between DTOs and DAOs, so I chose [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/). The Mapper is not able to detect the setters I have defined in my DAOs.

The problem is exactly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770813/mapping-an-object-to-an-immutable-object-with-builder-using-immutables-annotati). This question does not have an accepted answer and I have tried all of the suggestions in that question and they don't work. I don't want to try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825324/4054389) because I feel it defeats the purpose for which I am using Immutables. @marc-von-renteln summarizes this reason nicely in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770813/mapping-an-object-to-an-immutable-object-with-builder-using-immutables-annotati#comment76722544_44825324)

I tried the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48228965/4054389) provided by @tobias-schulte. But that caused a different problem. In the Mapper class in the answer, trying to return Immutable*.Builder from the mapping method throws an error saying the Immutable type cannot be found.

I have exhaustively searched issues logged against MapStruct and Immutables and I haven't been able to find a solution. Unfortunately there are hardly few examples or people using a combination of MapStruct and Immutables. The [mapstruct-examples](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples) repository also doesn't have an example for working with Immutables.

I even tried defining separate Mapper interfaces for each of the DtTOs (like UserStatusMapper). I was only making it more complicated with more errors.

I have created a sample spring project to demonstrate the problem.
[GitHub Repo Link](https://github.com/deepaks829/demo). This demo app is almost same as the REST service I am creating. All database (spring-data-jpa , hibernate) stuff is removed and I am using mock data.
If you checkout the project and run the demo-app you can make two API calls.

GetUser:
Request:
http://localhost:8080/user/api/v1/users/1
Response:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "username": "TestUser",
    "email": "TestUser@demo.com",
    "userStatus": {
        "id": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "statusName": "Active"
    }
```

Createuser: PROBLEM HERE
http://localhost:8080/user/api/v1/users/create
Sample Input:

```
{
    "username": "TestUser",
    "email": "TestUser@demo.com",
    "userStatus": {
        "id": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "statusName": "Active"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-28T09:29:24.933+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.model.ImmutableUserDto$Builder]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.model.ImmutableUserDto$Builder`, problem: Cannot build UserDto, some of required attributes are not set [username, email, userStatus]\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 9, column: 1]",
    "path": "/user/api/v1/users/create"
}
```

Below are important pieces of code related to problem:

*Daos:*
*1. UserDao*

```
public class User {

    // Primary Key. Something that is annotated with @Id
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private UserStatus userStatus;

    private User(Builder builder) {
        id = builder.id;
        username = builder.username;
        email = builder.email;
        userStatus = builder.userStatus;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public UserStatus getUserStatus() {
        return userStatus;
    }

    public static final class Builder {
        private int id;
        private String username;
        private String email;
        private UserStatus userStatus;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public Builder setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setUserStatus(UserStatus userStatus) {
            this.userStatus = userStatus;
            return this;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new User(this);
        }
```

*2. UserStatusDao:*

```
package com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dao.model;

/**
 * Status of user.
 * Example: Active or Inactive
 */
public class UserStatus {
    // Primary Key. Something that is annotated with @Id
    private int id;
    // A value of 1 or 0
    private int status;
    // Active , InActive
    private String statusName;

    private UserStatus(Builder builder) {
        id = builder.id;
        status = builder.status;
        statusName = builder.statusName;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getStatusName() {
        return statusName;
    }

    public static final class Builder {
        private int id;
        private int status;
        private String statusName;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public Builder setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setStatusName(String statusName) {
            this.statusName = statusName;
            return this;
        }

        public UserStatus build() {
            return new UserStatus(this);
        }
    }
}
```

*DTOs*
*1. UserDto:*

```
package com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(defaults = @Value.Immutable(copy = false), init = "set*")
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableUserDto.class)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableUserDto.Builder.class)
public abstract class UserDto {

    @Value.Default
    @JsonProperty
    public int id() {
        return 0;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public abstract String username();

    @JsonProperty
    public abstract String email();

    @JsonProperty
    public abstract UserStatusDto userStatus();
```

*2. UserStatusDto:*

```
package com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(defaults = @Value.Immutable(copy = false), init = "set*")
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableUserStatusDto.class)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableUserStatusDto.Builder.class)
public abstract class UserStatusDto {

    @JsonProperty
    public abstract int id();

    @JsonProperty
    public abstract int status();

    @JsonProperty
    public abstract String statusName();

}
```

MapStruct UserMapper:

```
package com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.mapper;

import com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dao.model.User;
import com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dao.model.UserStatus;
import com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.model.UserDto;
import com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.model.UserStatusDto;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper USER_MAPPER_INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDto userDaoToDto(User user);

    //Problem here.
    User userDtoToDao(UserDto userDto);

    UserStatusDto userStatusDaoToDto(UserStatus userStatusDao);
    UserStatus userStatusDtoToDao(UserStatusDto userStatusDto);
}
```

If I look at the concrete method generated by MapStruct for `userDtoToDao` I can clearly see that the setters are not being recognized.

```
package com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.mapper;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2019-04-28T02:29:03-0700",
    comments = "version: 1.3.0.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {
...
...
    @Override
    public User userDtoToDao(UserDto userDto) {
        if ( userDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dao.model.User.Builder user = User.builder();

        return user.build();
    }
....
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapstruct doesn't recognize your getters in `UserDto` and `UserStatusDto`.

When you change the existing methods (like `public abstract String username()`) in these abstract classes to classic getters like

```
@JsonProperty("username")
public abstract String getUsername();
```

the `MapperImpl` will contain the required calls. Note, that the `@JsonProperty` needs to have the attributes name itself afterwards (because of the changed method name).

Here are the complete classes `UserDto` and `UserStatusDto` with said changes:

```
package com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(defaults = @Value.Immutable(copy = false), init = "set*")
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableUserDto.class)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableUserDto.Builder.class)
public abstract class UserDto {

    @Value.Default
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int getId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @JsonProperty("username")
    public abstract String getUsername();

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public abstract String getEmail();

    @JsonProperty("userStatus")
    public abstract UserStatusDto getUserStatus();

}
```

```
package com.immutablesmapstruct.demo.dto.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(defaults = @Value.Immutable(copy = false), init = "set*")
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableUserStatusDto.class)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableUserStatusDto.Builder.class)
public abstract class UserStatusDto {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public abstract int getId();

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public abstract int getStatus();

    @JsonProperty("statusName")
    public abstract String getStatusName();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for response @dersvenhesse. That solved my problem :)